# Trigger event using dataLayer does not work

Tags: google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I have problems with trigger my event. In my code:

```
<script>
    dataLayer.push({
        'event' : 'GAEvent',
        'eventCategory' : 'overlayer',
        'eventAction' : 'popup [overlayer]',
        'eventLabel' : undefined,
        'eventValue' : undefined
    });
</script>
```

In the preview mode my custom event isn`t trigger because of _event rule

[image]

which I didnt create in GTM. My trigger from GTM:

[image]

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: Thas an internal event that is linked to the rules "when your event will fire" in the tag setup.  Check your logic in there is correct - I often put a regex in that field without changing it to a regex type, for instance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying "Check your logic"? I update my question post with trigger image settings from GTM.

Comment: The logic is the "equals" in the screenshot above.  Try deleting the event filter (hit - next to it): it shouldn't be necessary. (You will see "Add Filters" button once its done). Thats where the _event trigger is referencing.

Comment: Ok. I removed event filter. But in the preview mode still _event is not equal GaEvent.

Comment: Ahh, you are passing in GAEvent, but the Event Name in your Fire On is GaEvent.  Change that to uppercase.

Comment: Oh my god, what a silly mistake. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in "GAEvent" as a dataLayer event, but had the incorrect field in your GTM trigger looking for it. (Screenshot shows "GaEvent").

You also don't need the filter field, which is where you originally put in the uppercase verion.

Change that to the same as the event you are passing in, "GAEvent".

There is always confusion on which events we are talking of, GA, GTM or JavaScript :)